# What are the consequences of unregistering the service worker in create-react-app project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker

I have a create-react-app project and I am running into an issue when there is a new production release the users don't get the latest version unless the clear the cache or in the best scenario when refreshing the page after they access it.
My Cloudflare cache expiry is set to 4 hours, but obviously the users still get the old version after this period. This leaves me thinking that it is a service worker issue.
Are there any other reasons that lead to this behaviour?
What are the possible solutions?
Is unregistering the SW considered a good solution for this issue? Knowing that I don't need my app to run offline at the moment.
If it is a good solution what are the consequences of unregistering it?
Do I need to use cache-control headers (ie max-age=0) in my index.html?

I know it is a lot of questions, but I wanted to show the directions I am thinking of and the areas I am bit confused about.

Thank you for your time and help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding versioning to your service worker cache is one of the ways you can ensure the new service worker gets installed whenever there is a new build. Just add a script which increments the version of the cache with each new build which causes a byte difference in service worker which in enough for the browser to trigger the new install event.

In your service worker file add something like

```
const version = 1;
let cacheV = 'foo' + version;
```

In your Activate event add logic that if there is a version mismatch delete the old cache.

```
self.addEventListener("activate", function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames) {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.map(function(cacheName) {
          if (cacheV!== cacheName &&  cacheName.startsWith("foo")) {
            return caches.delete(cacheName);
          }
        })
      );
    })
  );
});
```

Also you can add update logic to your fetch listener which will fetch the latest file from network like

```
event.waituntil(update(request));
```